# Extracting and sorting top int value out of a list of Strings

Tags: java, while-loop, parseint

I have a java program that is scanning a text file with the following information:

Advanced Martial Arts Diploma
 (Burbanks Ninja School)
    Adkins,
Scott   72
 Black, Jack  44
 Carradine, David 81
 Chan, Jackie
    75
 Chow, Stephen    77
 Chow, Yung-Fat   79
 Jaa, Tony    71
Lee, Bruce  76
 Li, Jet  76
 Norris, Chuck    71
 Oedekerk,
Steve   58
 Reeves, Keanu    62
 Uwais, Iko   75
 Yen, Donnie
    80
 Yeoh, Michelle   79
 Zhang, Ziyi  75
  
 Pilot
(Starfleet Academy)
  Archer, Jonathan   71
 Janeway,
Kathryn 74
 Kirk, James T.   79
 Picard, Jean-Luc     85
 Pike,
Christopher     80
 Riker, William   79
   Advanced Action Heroes
(Disney U)
   Aladdin    91
 Benedict, Julius 45
 Brewer,
Gordy   82
 Conan    60
 Duck, Donald 40
 Iincredible, Mr. 85
Matrix, John    64
 Mouse, Mickey    51
 Owens, Ray   82
 Poppins,
Mary    85
 Quaid, Douglas   75
 Richards, Ben    68
 Simba    80
Slater, Jack    80
 Terminator, The  90
 Tully, Louis DNF
     
Attire, Poise & Grace
 Bieber, Justin    33
 Bullock,
Sandra  80
 Ciccone, Madonna 60
 Cyrus, Miley 40
 Gaga,
Lady    50
 Lauper, Cindi    55
 Minaj, Nicki 45
 Sarkisian,
Cher    75

That's All, Folks!

Here is my code so far to scan the text file and return the formatted values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("lists.txt"));
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine().trim();

    String programName;
    String schoolName;
    String topStudent;
    int topGrade;



    while (!line.equals("That's All, Folks!")) {
        //extract a program's information
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(line.trim());
        line = fileScanner.nextLine().trim();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println("");
        while (!line.isEmpty()) {

            //deal with one student                
            System.out.println(line);
            line = fileScanner.nextLine().trim();
            line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        }
        //displays summary information for a program    
        line = fileScanner.nextLine().trim();
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to check these strings (some have one, and some have two names.  One has a DNF instead of a grade).  How would I go about only returning the name and top grade of each person in each program to look like below:

Advanced Martial Arts Diploma 
 (Burbanks Ninja School) 
David
Carradine

Pilot
 (Starfleet Academy)
 Jean-Luc Picard

Advanced Action Heroes 
Disney U) 
Aladdin

Attire, Poise & Grace 
Sandra Bullock

EDIT: added variables

Comment: You forgot to include your own attempt.

Comment: Yeah, I have absolutely no idea where to go after sorting the list.  That's why I'm asking for help here.

Comment: But you haven't done any sorting yet. You don't have a datastructure that holds the entries and alternatively you don't have variables where you store the best person for each program. You only parse the file, but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: I added variables for programName, schoolName, topGrade, and topStudent

Comment: It compiles for me.  I just don't know how to now sort each of the students by grade and return the top grade

Answer (score 2):

So a good place to start would be

```
line = line.replaceAll(", ", ",");
String[] split = line.split(" ");
```

in the split array your going to have [name, mark] if its a person or just [name] if its the name of the academy.

Comment: Would I put this in the inner loop?

Comment: Yep, if you just play around with that i'm sure you'll be able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like at this point you're just printing `String`s and then tossing them out.

It also looks like you're dealing with several different types of information (academy, names, grade)

This will be hard to deal with later on if you're just using `String`s. I would start by building a couple of data structures to hold the different kinds of information as you parse the file.

So perhaps you could have an `Academy` class that has many `Student` objects, and each `Student` has a name, etc.